# Passing Value from Azure Logic Apps to HttpTrigger Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App, which executes a stored procedure in Azure SQL. Stored proc returns me a single value and that value has to be passed to Azure function in the HttpRequest. As per the run history  of the Logic App, the HttpTrigger status is showing as Skipped.

*Below is the logic app and its run history*

**Logic App**

*Passing value to Azure function*

[image: Logic App designer]

*After triggering the Logic App*

[image: Logic App designer]

*Run history of the logic app*

[image: Logic App run history]

It would be helpful if someone can help me in identifying the reason for Azure function status as 'Skipped'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test and get the same result as yours.

[image]

Go to check your Logic Apps Run history, check the SQL action Outputs, your value in the body must be null like the below picture shows.

[image]

In this situation, the logic app won't continue execute the next action.

Then i add the value into my table and test again. It works fine this time.

[image]